# Codeigniter 3 - Count rows from one table and join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to join two table and count all results from **messageFiles** which are related to **message**
I have tables with following structure:

**messages**:

```
id
name
email
subject
message
date_added
read
```

**messagesFiles**

```
id
name
message_id
date_added
```

I am trying this code, but I always get result **countFiles** = 1 and I **message** is repeated for every file that is related to it (for example if I have 3 files for the message, it will be repeated 3 times). Also messages which doesn't have files will not be selected by this query. What's seems to be a problem?

```
$this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, messages.*, COUNT(messagesFiles.id) as countFiles", FALSE)->from('messages')
        ->join('messagesFiles', "messagesFiles.message_id = messages.id")
        ->where("messages.read", 1)
        ->group_by('messagesFiles.id')->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: how many rows are you getting back? How many rows do you get if you remove COUNT() and group_by()?

Comment: There are total 8 rows without the COUNT() and group_by

Comment: And how rows do you get back with COUNT() and group_by?

Comment: 14 - this is the number of rows in the **messageFiles** table.

Comment: This doesn't make sense... when you use group_by you should have fewer rows than when you don't

Comment: Did you tried the query within `sql`

Answer (score 0):

You could try some thing like this code below and add `return  $this->db->count_all_results()`.

http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html

```
public function count_test() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from('category c');
    $this->db->join('category_description cd', "cd.category_id = c.category_id");
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```